# Mount a Rackspace drive in Linux

Tags: filesystems, mount, remote

Is there any software that will allow me to mount a Rackspace drive in linux? I want to copy SQL files from my database onto my Rackspace. I have web min running a backup nightly and copying those backups offsite would be ideal for obvious reasons.

On my Windows desktop I've been using Cyberduck to upload/download and manage files on the server.

I purchased a subscription to "Jungle Disk" but this problem was unstable on all the systems I had available in my office — Ubuntu and Windows 7. The application itself seems alright but any click took on average 10 seconds to respond.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to the most simple way to copy this stuff to Rackspace? I have a Cloud Files account and am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

As [the Wikipedia article on Rackspace Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rackspace_Cloud#Cloud_Files) states, there is no native way to mount such virtual drive:

> Caveats
>
> There is no native operating system support for the Cloud Files API so it is not yet possible to "map" or "mount" it as a virtual drive without third-party software like JungleDisk that translates to a supported standard such as WebDAV. There are no concepts of "appending" or "locking" data within Cloud Files (which may affect some disk mirroring or backup solutions), nor support for permissions or transcoding. Data is organised into "containers" but it is not possible to create nested folders without a translation layer.

However, quick googling reveals projects like [Cloudfuse](https://github.com/redbo/cloudfuse) and [MossoFS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120715233002/http://westhoffswelt.de:80/projects/mossofs.html) that profide a [fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)-based mounting solutions.