# Mount Google Drive in Linux?

Tags: filesystems, mount, cloud, google-drive

Now that [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) is available, how do we mount it to a Linux filesystem? Similar solutions exist for [Amazon S3](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) and [Rackspace Cloud Files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23646/mount-a-rackspace-drive-in-linux).

Comment: Share your support: https://plus.google.com/s/%23DriveForLinux/posts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### `rclone`

**rclone** is an option that you can get through your package manager without adding a PPA.

It is a command-line tool for working with *various* cloud storage services including Google Drive, Amazon S3, Dropbox, Box... and it can be used to mount your Google Drive as a virtual file system:

```bsh
sudo apt install rclone
rclone config # See config process below
mkdir ~/drive
rclone mount $NAME_OF_RCLONE_REMOTE: ~/drive/
```

#### Configuring rclone

1. Enter `n` for "New remote"
2. Enter any arbitrary name for your remote, referenced in the steps above as `$NAME_OF_RCLONE_REMOTE`
3. The program prints a list of cloud services. Find "Google Drive" and enter the number for it
4. The program prompts you for a few more pieces of information
5. You'll perform an Oauth authentication
6. Enter `q` to finish

See a more detailed walkthrough at https://ostechnix.com/how-to-mount-google-drive-locally-as-virtual-file-system-in-linux/

Comment: Oh wow, looks like rclone has had this feature since 2015. It's one of my favorite tools and I didn't even realize this! Here is the relevant manual page: https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/

Comment: In 2021 this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 39):

Grive or inSync is a file sync tool which syncs up a local file system and remote Google Drive. You cannot "mount" Google Drive using these tools.

For mounting, use [google-drive-ocamlfuse](http://gdfuse.forge.ocamlcore.org/), FUSE-based filesystem for Google Drive.

Installation instructions, and more details about configuration, and authorization are at the [Installation of FUSE filesystem over Google Drive](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Installation) wiki page (on GitHub).

The project's GitHub homepage also has the readme file that is for the `google-drive-ocamlfuse` source code.

Here are distro-specific [instructions to mount Google Drive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180826162814/http://xmodulo.com/mount-google-drive-linux.html) with google-drive-ocamlfuse.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  This looks like a great tool.  One caveat seems to be that it requires a web browser to authenticate with oauth2. You may want to edit your answer to indicate as such.

Comment: Yes, but there is a workaround to get authorization on a headless host (https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Headless-Usage-%26-Authorization). You will still need a browser, but it does not have to be on the same machine.

Comment: Now in 2017, is there any updates? or it is still the only solution?

Comment: Does OCamlFuse support mounting ONLY certain directories? The Docs has not mentioned such a feature... But I think it's absolutely necessary. My whole Google Drive will be pretty big, and I don't need all the directories really.

Comment: @aderchox from what I  understand, it is mounted as remote storage, much like a samba share. It is not synced on the local system. Files in drive stay in drive. any this you want to move to drive needs to be moved to mounted network drive. So you are not affected how many folders your drive has.

Answer (score 13):

An open source client for Google Drive exists: [Grive](http://github.com/Grive/grive).

> For now, the application is considered experimental and it lacks full sync, but it can upload and download new or changed files already (so you can access your files offline). What it can't do yet is: wait for changes and automatically sync the files or delete files (when a file is deleted locally, it's ignored and when it's deleted remotely, it's reuploaded if it exists locally).

Sources and binaries are available on [Github](http://github.com/Grive/grive). A third party, webupd8, has provided a [PPA for Ubuntu](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/grive-open-source-google-drive-client.html).

Note that this project is [officially abandoned since September 2018](https://github.com/Grive/grive/commit/7b4797a406f10de1e2549ccf36bbed2e40c414a0).

Comment: Currently a dead link - try: https://github.com/Grive/grive

Comment: According to the docs, `grive` seems not to be able to access Google Docs, but for that the other answer could help: <http://code.google.com/p/google-docs-fs/wiki/OnlineManual>. Am I right that they complement each other?

Comment: Isn't that curious that `grive` tries to mimick the "syncing" behaviour of a Gogle Drive client, rather then following the traditional Unix approach of mounting a filesystem? For me, it would seem more convenient to decide which file on the remote FS I want to open, and only then the transfer would happen. What if I don't want to sync every file? Of course, syncing rather then mounting can make sense inside an implementation of a distributed FS, rather then centralized remote FS -- look at `git-annex` as a possible implementaton of a distributed FS. Mounting then could be made on top of sync.

Comment: No updates for over 2 years. This seems abandoned.

Comment: An officially abandoned project.

Answer (score 5):

There is an SDK available, so someone will probably make a linux solution soon.  There is also a drive on Google+ going on right now to get Google to add a Linux client, in addition to the Windows, Mac, and Android clients (not to mention their plans for an iOS client.)

Then they will be on par with Dropbox :)  (with a bit more extra free space by default)

Comment: Yeah, they announced it's on it's way. But still no Linux client. I was hoping for an implementation by the open community with FUSE or something...

Comment: Is there a source for this announcement?

Comment: I don't think we ever got one

Answer (score 4):

A [package from Luca Invernizzi](https://launchpad.net/~invernizzi) exists to do so. See http://code.google.com/p/google-docs-fs/wiki/OnlineManual.

For Ubuntu:

First you need to add the packages provided by Luca and available in his PPA (Ubuntu 11.10 only at present):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:invernizzi/google-docs-fs
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-docs-fs
```

Once everything that’s needed has been installed log out and back in.

1. Open Nautilus Create a new folder in your Home folder titled `Drive`
2. Open a Terminal and run:  `gmount Drive username@gmail.com`
3. Input your password
4. Your Google Drive is now mounted in the `Drive` folder

Source: [How to access Google Drive via Nautilus in Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-access-google-drive-via-nautilus-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: It seems it's only for Google Docs. The docs are just a part of Google Drive; am I right? But then there's `grive` from the other answer to access everything but the docs.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 (ARM, not the usual i386) I could `wget` and install with `dpkg --install` [the "gdrive" package](https://launchpad.net/~invernizzi/+archive/google-docs-fs/+files/google-docs-fs_1.0%7Egdrive_all.deb) form there -- after `apt-get install python-gdata python-fuse`.

Comment: To download the deb and install after the `apt-get install python-gdata python-fuse` is still working. it didn't prompt on wrong password.

Answer (score 4):

[Insync](http://insynchq.com) is a Linux client for Google Drive with the following features:

- multiple Google accounts support
- offline Google docs editing
- right-click share in the context menu
- recent changes notifications
- external hard drive support
- support for the most popular distributions (Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Debian, Fedora, openSUSE)
- support for the most popuar desktop environments (Unity, MATE, GNOME Shell, Cinnamon, KDE 4, Xfce)
- support for multiple file managers (Nautilus, Caja, Nemo, Dolphin, Thunar)

Learn more at [insynchq.com/linux](http://insynchq.com/linux).

*Disclaimer:* I'm one of the developers of Insync.

Answer (score 2):

I've just discovered [insync](https://forums.insynchq.com/discussion/1545/insync-for-linux-beta-10-0-9-25). I don't know how good it is; it seems to be closed source.

PD (2018/12/28): After several years using insync I can strongly recommend it as a Linux desktop synchronizer for Google Drive. Check [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37234/mount-google-drive-in-linux/61224#61224) for more feature details.

Comment: @reducingactivity the linked answer was posted 2 months after this one.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use an online service to access Google Drive using WebDAV (e.g. using http://synqya.appspot.com) so there is no need for a client installation or other add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not a filesystem mount via the Linux kernel, [KIO GDrive](https://community.kde.org/KIO_GDrive) (part of KDE) enables KIO-aware applications (such as the Dolphin file manager, Kate editor, or Gwenview image viewer) to access, navigate, and edit Google Drive files.

`kio-gdrive` is available as package in several Linux distributions. If installed, the Dolphin file manager will get an entry "Google Drive" under "Network". There, an unprivileged desktop user can 'mount' a GoogleDrive account via a guided graphical configuration (during which the default browser will be opened where one needs to give KDE KAaccounts permission to access the GoogleDrive account).

This method doesn't provide access to GoogleDrive via a terminal, but it integrates it nicely with a graphical desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Google drive can be mounted with GNOME online accounts. Under settings -> User accounts you can login with your google credentials and get you google drive mounted easily.

Answer (score -1):

Insync is actually the best client for Google Driver around

https://www.insynchq.com

It's full featured, and free during the beta phase.

Answer (score -2):

I followed the instructions here:

http://xmodulo.com/2013/10/mount-google-drive-linux.html

and got it to work successfully on Fedora 16.

This builds google-drive-ocamlfuse, which is then used to access google drive.

Comment: This is your opinion, without supplying any facts as to why "it did not work for you" not really answer and a poor comment too.

Comment: Please review my updated post, it provides factual information.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but now you've got a subset of the information that's in the accepted answer.