# Is there a way to access Google Drive spreadsheet?

Tags: filesystems, mount, cloud

I'm using Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon. I tried `google-drive-ocamlfuse` and `grive`, but both of them can't access spreadsheet. `google-drive-ocamlfuse` shows this error:

> Device or resource busy

W hen it tries to access `.ods` file?  Is there any alternative which can access?

Actually I have many `.ods` Or `.xls` files which are to be shared with many different collaborators who can edit it. Up to this it is okay, it can be done using Google Drive . But now I have to use these files in Mathematica?

So instead of Google Drive if there is any site which can edit Dropbox `.xls` files and save them, that would suffice for my job.

Or if there is any other alternative for my purpose please let me know.

I've read this one: [Mount Google Drive in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37234/mount-google-drive-in-linux), but the question was asked two years before, so there may be new updates and my problem is also different from that.