# How to download a folder from google drive using terminal?

Tags: wget, download

I want to download a folder from my google drive using terminal? Is there any way to do that? I tried this:

```
$ wget "https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-Zc9K0k9q-WWUlqMXAyTG40MjA&usp=sharing"
```

But it is downloading this text file: `folderview?id=0B-Zc9K0k9q-WdEY5a1BCUDBaejQ&usp=sharing`. Is there any way to download google drive folder from terminal?

Comment: Check [*Mount Google Drive in Linux?*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37234/62558).

Comment: I have checked them but they can't handle google spreadsheet. As I need access to spreadsheet and `ocamlfuse` can handle this, I thought of downloading them everytime I need them though time comsuming with respect to mount. But I have no other options.

Comment: Set the folder setting to "anyone on the internet can find and view", then you will be able to download the file with `wget https://googledrive.com/host/file_id` for you that is `wget https://googledrive.com/host/0B-Zc9K0k9q-WdEY5a1BCUDBaejQ`. Solution explained [here in more details](http://mynixworld.info/2013/02/23/transparently-download-from-google-drive/).

Comment: Any new answers for this during the time passed? we have one option below.

Comment: this also seems like a very useful and related link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive

Answer (score 59):

I was able to download a public shared file using this command:

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O FILENAME
```

Where `FILEID` must be replaced by the actual file ID. `FILENAME` is the path/filename where download will be stored.

Note you cannot use a folderid instead of fileid. I have used view source in a folder view where I could find the following HTML `<div id="entry-0B0jxxycBojSwVW...`. The string starting with `0B` was the fileid.

Comment: This worked great for me! just had to use drive.google.com instead

Comment: since I had a large file I kept getting the google virus scanner warning (that it can't scan). I did not find a solution for this problem. However, I realized that I could simply use `scp` to transfer the file to my server (which had the need for such downloading)

Comment: this is not working anymore with google drive...

Comment: This won't work for larger files. This answer in stack overflow works like a charm : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32742700/4773609

Comment: @HGSur My answer below also works for large files.

Comment: I am currently not able to verify this, but [vasiliki](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/359663/vasiliki) suggested the following: The way to find the file's unique ID is to right click on the file and click `Get Shareable Link` option. There you must turn it on and then from the link, the part after `id=` is your file ID.

Comment: It doest not work for folders!

Comment: Hello, does this work also for password protected folders with username?

Comment: do you have a solution for entire folders in gdrive?

Comment: I honestly wonder what people think when they just keep upvoting unrelated answer. OP is asking for a folder not a file

Answer (score 22):

2 useful Python programs (require: `sudo apt install -y python3 python3-pip`):

- [gdown](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown): Download a large file public from Google Drive (curl/wget fails due to security notice).   `pip install gdown`
- [gshell](https://github.com/wkentaro/gshell): Navigate in Google Drive as you do on shell (gshell = Google Drive + Shell). `pip install gshell` (maybe [discontinued](https://github.com/wkentaro/gshell/issues/18))

To upload to GDrive, one can use https://labbots.github.io/google-drive-upload/.

---

Examples:

To download 1 public large file from Google Drive (5 GB):

```
# syntax: gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=FILE-ID
gdown https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1LC5iVcvgksQhNVJ-CbMigqXnPAaquiA2
```

To download 1 folder:

```
gshell init              # log in to your Google account 
gshell ll                # list files
gshell download spam.txt # download file -> you could script to download all files listed by gshell ll
```

I use `gdown` and it works well. I haven't tried `gshell`.

Note that if one uses `gdown` more than ~20 times within 24 hours (might depend on the file size), we get the error:

> Access denied with the following error:
>
> ```
>   Too many users have viewed or downloaded this file recently. Please
>   try accessing the file again later. If the file you are trying to
>   access is particularly large or is shared with many people, it may
>   take up to 24 hours to be able to view or download the file. If you
>   still can't access a file after 24 hours, contact your domain
>   administrator.
> ```
>
> You may still be able to access the file from the browser:
>
> ```
>     https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1LC5iVcvgksQhNVJ-CbMigqXnPAaquiA2
> ```

Comment: this worked like an absolute charm, thank you! this was quick an easy and IMO should definitely be more of an accepted answer. i guess maybe the handicap is having to install python, instead of a more direct native CLI program (but your instructions are directly copy & pastable)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: gshell unfortunately redirects to https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/danger, which tells me that the app has been temporarily disabled

Comment: `gdown` does not continue to download if the download operation is crashed

Comment: this is the easiest way to download and should have a lot more upvotes

Comment: `gshell` works perfectly even for shared link, all you have to do open link on the browser and select `Add shortcut to Drive` and the file will be available on your account files list

Answer (score 14):

A newer, open-source multi-platform client, written in Go called [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) is quite nice and full-featured, and also is in active development.

#### Examples

> The pull command downloads data from Google Drive that does not exist locally, and deletes local data that is not present on Google Drive. Run it without any arguments to pull all of the files from the current path:
>
> ```
> $ drive pull
> ```
>
> Pulling by matches is also supported
>
> ```
> $ cd ~/myDrive/content/2015
> $ drive pull --matches vines docx
> ```

See the above link for further examples, these are just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: This tool is not maintained since September 2017

Comment: Yes but it still works and to download a whole directory it's the best solution: `drive pull 'Colab Notebooks/sorted/models/resnet-101-90.9-max-acc'`. The other methods are a pain in the ass.

Comment: `gdrive` is the current up-to-date solution, also written in Go, even easier than the above one https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive For instance, to download a folder you do `gdrive download --recursive FOLDER_ID_FROM_URL`, no config necessary, it will ask for your credentials.

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with this tool - it works as advertised, but the definitions they use take some time to get used to. Note that `copy` means copying inside the drive - not to your local machine, and download is `pull`. I blew up my Google Drive trying to "copy" files to my local machine and was surprised to never get any local files.

Answer (score 14):

There is a giant program in the ubuntu 17.04 repository called: rclone

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install rclone

$ rclone config --> than follow the steps to setup your gdrive
```

now you can rclone copy and sync everything you want. The projects supports all kinds of clouds.. f.e.:

```
$ rclone sync /home/<usrname>/Desktop/yourfolder gdrivename:yourfolder
```

[[1]: https://rclone.org](http://rclone.org)

(btw I uploaded about 600GB and transferred 1TB with rclone from gdrive to gdrive in few hours, gdrive to ubuntu and ubuntu to gdrive.. and it works terrific over weeks in a row!!

```
https://forum.rclone.org/t/can-copy-between-google-drive-accounts-without-download-and-upload-files/969/8
```

)

Comment: Documentation is lacking. Following the steps one by one doesn't work.

Comment: Be careful about the order in `rclone sync a b`. I created a test dir and did `rclone sync testdir drive:/important_folder and it attempted to delete all the files in `drive:/important_folder. Fortunately, I had only given `drive.readonly` access to my drive. Reversing the order of arguments works.

Comment: The setup is quite complex, but documentation is much better now. I also recommend using rclone-browser as a (mostly) graphical UI to rclone and makes using it much easier (it does not help with configuration though - you should still expect to need to read a lot of stuff and follow complex directions). You should probably allocate at least half an hour to setting this up, unless you have a lot of experience setting up GCP projects.

Comment: Unfortunately I have too low rep to add another answer about `rclone`, but this actually works -- look at answers here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37234/mount-google-drive-in-linux It took me ~20 mins to go through enabling Google Drive API access, `rclone config` (you need to paste the client ID and secret there), then `rclone ls gdrive:` (`gdrive:` is the name you give to the _remote_ you create in `rclone config`).

Answer (score 10):

You can use the open source Linux / Unix command line tool [`gdrive`](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive).

**To install it:**

1. **[Download](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive#downloads) the binary.** Choose the one that fits your architecture, for example `gdrive-linux-x64`.
2. **Copy it to your path.**

   ```
   sudo cp gdrive-linux-x64 /usr/local/bin/gdrive;
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/gdrive;
   ```

**To use it:**

1. **Determine the Google Drive folder's ID.** For that, go inside the folder to download, using the drive.google.com web client. Now look at the URL in the browser's address bar, it will show something like `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7_OwkDsUIgFWXA1B2FPQfV5S8H`. Obtain the string behind the last `/` and copy it to your clipboard. That's the folder's ID.
2. **Download the folder.** Of course, use your folder's ID instead in the following command.

   ```
   gdrive download --recursive 0B7_OwkDsUIgFWXA1B2FPQfV5S8H
   ```

At first usage, the tool will need to obtain access permissions to the Google Drive API. For that, it will show you a link which you have to visit in a browser, and then you will get a verification code to copy&paste back to the tool. The download then starts automatically. There is no progress indicator, but you can observe the progress in a file manager or second terminal.

**Source:** [A comment by Tobi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010369/wget-curl-large-file-from-google-drive#comment43929971_25033499) in a stackoverflow.com question. Answer adapted from [my similar answer over there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32441141).

Comment: Can't get permission?
Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

Comment: Same here: "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app"

Answer (score 9):

you can try, if you are on firefox, installing cliget addon. For every file that you want to download program show you curl, wget or aria2 direct link for downloading that file. I use that to download files on other machines via ssh because it's much faster for me to download directly to remote computer then to upload that file from my computer. This also work with dropbox, gdrive etc.

Comment: This is by far the best answer! Thank you!

Comment: This is not even an answer. OP wants it via terminal not manually

Answer (score 8):

`wget` can only handle direct links, but that is not the main problem here. Google Drive expects you to authenticate before downloading your file. This means you will have to use a web browser to download the file. There are a few web browsers for the terminal, [lynx](http://lynx.browser.org/) is an example.

If you choose to publicly share your file (so that anyone can download it) you can use one of the numerous Google Drive permalink services. I believe these should produce links that will work with wget. Here is a list of two I found when searching for information:
http://gdriveurl.com/
http://gdurl.com/

Assuming you are running Linux there is an open source [client](https://github.com/Grive/grive) for Google Drive that might be worth looking into.

Comment: lynx is showing "redirecting" for more than 5 minutes when trying to access the drive. "Google Drive permalink" is ok, but I don't want to share it with everyone. I have used `Grive` and `Ocamlfuse` but they can't access spreadsheets

Comment: Confirmed the "download" link from gdriveurl worked with wget

Comment: regarding the open source client suggestion: from my experience using that gdrive client and a similar utility called rclone, I have had better experiences with rclone.

Answer (score 2):

Download binary from the below [link](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive)

```
chmod +x <binary>
./drive download id
```

It will generate link for verification code. Click the link and allow access to gdrive and copy the verification code from browser. Paste it.

It works for me