# Upload file to Google Docs with a script

Tags: scripting, synchronization, google, google-drive, upload

I want to upload a file to Google Docs with a script, to avoid doing it manually over and over again.

Is there a way to do that simpler than scripting this with a Selenium what would be really fragile?

To avoid XY problem: I have an .ods file on my Lubuntu OS that I want to have regularly copied to my Android phone in human-readable format.

I am not interested in mounting Google Drive - there is [a separate question for that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37234/mount-google-drive-in-linux) and accepted is not giving the ability to manipulate Google Docs.

Comment: Google Drive seems to have a [REST API available for uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads). You could use `curl` to script it.

Comment: @Haxiel Thanks! I am now writing a Python script. Can you make an answer that would be basically link to API docs (I may edit in my code into the answer) so I can mark you as the answerer?

Comment: Sure, I'll add a brief answer here pointing to the relevant sections of the API docs.

Comment: @Haxiel And now, as I have working code I also added it to the answer as promised. I must say that Google API has quite good documentation, at least for people starting to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Drive provides a REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) which can be used for integration.

Since file uploads are a core part of Google Drive's functionality, the API allows for different types of uploads: simple uploads, multi-part uploads, and resumable uploads. The details can be found at this link: [Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads).

Since you are planning to use Python for this task, a [quickstart guide for Python is also available](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python), including sample code to get you started.