# Uploading files from SUSE Linux to Google Drive using command line or shell

Tags: shell-script, opensuse, google-drive

How do I upload files from SUSE Linux to Google Drive using command line or shell scripting?

I have seen the question [Mount Google Drive in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37234/mount-google-drive-in-linux), which suggests "Grive" and "Gdrive", but these fail with `apps are unverified by the google`, so just I posted this for any latest solution for this.

Tried for many ways but not found any solution for SUSE Linux.

Comment: Possbly duplicated with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554638/uploade-and-updating-files-to-google-drive-via-cmd

Comment: @PauloTomé unfortunately, SE functionality does not let us close posts across sites like that. Feel free to import the appropriate answer here, with links/attribution back to the original. (Unless there's an on-site duplicate here?)

Comment: Possibly duplicated with: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37234/mount-google-drive-in-linux

Comment: they actually explain about grive  and gdrive i tried those  not worked.   its  showing like "apps are unverified by the google" like that so just i posted this for any latest solution for this

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [rclone](https://rclone.org/), it has support for [Google Drive](https://rclone.org/drive/). It should be available in openSUSE's repos.

> Rclone is a command line program to sync files and directories to and from [...]

The configuration for Google Drive is available [here](https://rclone.org/drive/) (basically, use `rclone config` and get a token from your Google account); then, once it's configured as a source, you can use [rclone's commands](https://rclone.org/docs/#subcommands) to copy data from/to it.